# Select content <Pre> when mouse click inside <Pre>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, blogger

I wanna select content Pre with single mouse click, and when Click Outside Pre deselect, This Code what I use, But is not working ...

```
var pres = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
for (var i = 0; i > pres.length; i++) {
    pres[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var selection = getSelection();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(this);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }, false);
}
```

anyOne help ...

Comment: Ummm ... `i > pres.length`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is the `for` loop condition,

```js
var pres = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
for (var i = 0; i <= pres.length; i++) { // Previously: for(var i = 0; i > pres.length; i++)
    pres[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var selection = getSelection();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(this);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }, false);
}
```

So you need to change the condition in your `for` loop.